# Run ColdFusion 9.02 on Apache 2.4 x64

Tags: apache, coldfusion, apache2.4, apache-modules

I've inherited an application server which I need to maintain/upgrade.
It's currently running Windows Server 2008R2, ColdFusion 9.02 32-bit and Apache 2.4 32-bit.
Because I want to upgrade/debug/alter the CF source code, I want to use FusionReactor to help me, especially the (line)debugging part.
Unfortunately, FusionReactor only runs (well, the debugging part) on 64bit java. Because the CF application is quite old, it's not ready to run on a newer CF version yet (and I want to port it to Lucee eventually). So, that leaves me the option of CF 9.02 64bit. Problem there is, that it won't run out of the box on Apache 2.4 (only 2.2).
CF 9.02 32bit is currently running on Apache 2.4 because I compiled/patched an Apache 2.2 module (mod_jrun22.so) so it works on Apache 2.4 (with the help of this https://g0blin.co.uk/mod_jrun-on-apache-2-4-ubuntu-14-04-coldfusion-9/ )
Unfortunately, I'm unable to do the same for Apache 2.4 64bit, because there seems to be no apxs 64bit available.
I could downgrade Apache 2.4 -> 2.2, but that's only my last resort.

Now my question. Is somebody able to recompile this module for 64bit, or give me some guidelines to do so? Is apxs available for 64bit? If not, Is there a simple way to compile (custom) modules for Apache 2.4 64bit?

Thanks!

Comment: I am also stucked in coldFusion9 migration to Apache2.4 from Apache 2.2  . Can you please help me with the steps . I just gone through "https://g0blin.co.uk/mod_jrun-on-apache-2-4-ubuntu-14-04-coldfusion-9/" .It seems to be for linux , not for windows

Comment: Hi. No, sorry. I gave up trying to get it work on CF 9.02 and I migrated our code to CF 2016 x64. It was the better choice in the long run, and it didn't involve much work actually. I tried for a bit to migrate it to Lucee, but ran in too many bugs there, and the cost for a CF 2016 license was way lower than the hours I would spend on getting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/multi-cfml-engine-install-extracting-the-coldfusion-9-connector-for-apache

```
Run it by ./apache_connectors.sh
If you get a GCC not found error, you might have to install some development tools,  
to allow you to build the connector.
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

You might reach out to Gavin, the author of that article to see if he has any further notes. It's been forever and a day since I had to deal w/ 32-bit CF. I know I managed to get CF 8 to run on 64-bit, which was never officially supported IIRC, but I don't have any of those notes anymore.

You might look to using CommandBox to run your server instead of Apache. It might make your conversion to Lucee easier too. The only reason to convert the engine depends on how much new code is being written for this application. You can get away with CF 9 without the effort of upgrading or converting.

Comment: @GunterO If you decide to go the CommandBox way, which I highly recommend, here are a couple of links to get you started: Running CommandBox Servers Behind IIS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8q7sSZ7gK3E Starting CommandBox Servers as a Windows Service https://youtu.be/-VyjpqlUi-U

Comment: @GunterO And here is a general primer for CommandBox https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox The beauty about CommandBox is that it takes minutes to install and you can spin up any version of ACF or Lucee Application Server, in seconds...

Comment: Thank you, will certainly look into CommandBox. Are there any limitations to CommandBox compared to Apache where I should be aware of? In terms of security, virtual hosts, ... just to name a few?